# how to configure web.xml for spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, classnotfoundexception

I am new to spring Framework and having problem with linking/configuring springframework through web.xml. 
I am getting below error when running my app.

Error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet


    type Exception report

    message Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

    description The server encountered an internal error (Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


    root cause 

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Apparently, it could not find class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in the Libraries. However, I dont know how to tell web.xml where to look for this class.

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
             xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>DispatcherSample</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>DispatcherSample</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/PlayField.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>Welcome.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

DispatcherSample-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">  
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="/PlayField.html">playfieldController</prop>
                </props>    
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="playfieldController" class="demos.PlayfieldController"/>

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

You must add [`spring-webmvc.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar) to your CLASSPATH (most likely to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory). The rest of your configuration seems fine.

Comment: added that to the directory, now getting    HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware

description The server encountered an internal error (org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: @Muhammad: make sure all your Spring JARs are in the same version and that you have `spring-context.jar` on your CLASSPATH as well.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I've added spring-context.jar (using same version for all jar files) and now its complaining about HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware. Please can you advise if there a full list of jar files to be used for spring mvc projects?

Comment: @Muhammad: start with `spring-beans`, `spring-aop`, `spring-core` and `spring-web`. There is no list because you typically choose what you want. Check out full listing though: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/

Comment: after adding the specified jars, i am now getting  HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware. I've tried adding spring-context.jar, but it causes tomcat to stop running.

Comment: ok, I had to add all Spring Framework libraries to resolve my issue. They were already present in java build path, why tomcat can't see these libraries and force to put them in the class path (WEB-INF/lib) folder instead?